# Can OS X automate creating a reminders from a page in a web browser?

Tags: safari, applescript, reminders

I enjoy the feature of creating reminders from a web page with one click. similar to how Omnifocus does this.

Can Apple's Reminders do the same by apple scripting or other addition/short cut?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add a selected text as a reminder

- Open Automator
- Create a new service
- Service receives selected **text** in **any application**
- Add a **Run ApplScript** Action
- Add the following script
- Save it

the script :

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Reminders"
        set theReminder to (make new reminder with properties {name:input})
        activate
    end tell

    return input
end run
```

Now when selecting text, you can with a right clic add it as a reminder. If you want that only in Safari. Replace the **any application** with **Safari** at the top of the Automator window.

And if you don't want to show the Application Reminders when adding a new one, just remove the line  **activate** in the script.

Comment: Nice idea, but please do some editing on the last sentence. What do you mean by "shop the App Reminders"?

Comment: 's/shop/show' done.